# How to generate a form in Django like in the admin?

Tags: django, forms

I'm using the app geoposition and when I enter in the admin I can see a form like this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppqtc.png

This is the repo of the app that I'm using: https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition

When I create the form it appears empty in the browser, this my code:

views.py

```
from geoposition.forms import GeopositionField

def add_route(request):
    form = GeopositionField()

    args = {}
    args = dict(form=form)

    return render_to_response("gestion/add_route.html", args)
```

add_route.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.media }}
     {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: A field is not a form. You'll need to create a form class with that field in.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it? I just spend two hours searching how to solve this problem ;_;

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/) on Django forms? Everything you need is there.

Answer (score 1):

views.py

```
from django import forms
from geoposition.forms import GeopositionField
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

class TestForm(forms.Form):   
    geo_position_field = GeopositionField()

def add_route(request):
    form = TestForm(request.POST)
    return render_to_response("gestion/add_route.html", {'form': form})
```

add_route.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

also you can use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) document to know more about django forms basics.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution.